# How to prevent POST methods from being accessed via GET in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, post, get, routes

I am using Codeigniter . I have the below method - create_client when the user submits a form with all details filled in .

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Admin extends CI_Controller {

public function create_client()
{

// catch all the form data here 
//process form data 


}

}
```

The function was designed for accepting a form submit . But if someone tries to access admin/create_client ( GET ) , he can directly execute the function as well . Since there is no form data via the GET statement , this leads to error .

How do I prevent the method being accessed via GET . One solution is to put some checks in the method -

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

// do things here 

} else  {

return false;

}
```

But I have a lot of such methods and I dont want to alter all such methods . Is there an easy way ? Say for example specifying in the Routes config that this method is a POST function and cant be accessed via GET ?

Comment: You might want to take a look at [Phil Sturgeon's CI RESTful Server implementation](https://github.com/philsturgeon/codeigniter-restserver), here is a [helpful tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/working-with-restful-services-in-codeigniter-2/).

Answer (score 0):

Try [remap](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/controllers.html#remapping):

```
public function _remap($method, $params = array())
{
    switch($method) {
        case 'post_method':
        case 'post_method2':
           if (! $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST')
               // return error
    }
    if (method_exists($this, $method))
       return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
    show_404();
}
```